# Dev Tools Inspect Devices very unreliable

Tags: google-smart-home

I'm currently going through the codelab [Enable local fulfillment for smart home Actions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-local/index.html). I managed to get (mostly) everything working.

But when I try to debug the typescript app Chrome using the Chrome Dev Tools (chrome://inspect/) I do sometimes see my Google Nest Mini to which the "local execution app" is deployed. But most of the times I do not. All my devices (Dev notebook and Google Nest Mini) are in the same IP subnet.

Any hints or ideas how to troubleshoot that?

Comment: Can you clarify whether the item missing from the DevTools list is the device itself (Nest Mini) or the local fulfillment app listed below it?

Comment: The device itself is missing in the DevTools list.

Comment: The problem is solved. I cleared the list of "
Target discovery settings", added the Google Nest Mini IP again and rebooted a few times. Since then it works always.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer your question with the resolution you discovered in case other developers experience the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I cleared the list of " Target discovery settings", added the Google Nest Mini IP again and rebooted a few times. Since then it works always.