# What port does the chrome dev tools Inspect devices connect to for local fulfillment?

Tags: google-smart-home

I am currently trying to develop a local home application, and for the most parts things are working as expected. The Google Home Nest Mini seems to be querying the test endpoint I set up and the ESP I'm using is receiving the discovery broadcast that, but the only issue I'm having is the chrome device debugger (chrome://inspect#devices) isn't finding the runtime of the Home Nest Mini. The debugger found it a few times, but it was inconsistent, and now I can't find it at all. I saw [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010978/dev-tools-inspect-devices-very-unreliable) that said they found specifying the IP and port of the Home Nest worked, but the ports that I found to be open using nmap don't change anything. Does someone know the port of the debugger service or a dummy-proof way of connecting the debugger?

Comment: After some digging I found the port to be 9222 if anyone else is looking for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As additional reference, [here are the instructions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/local#node.js_1) on setting this up (including the 9222 port as commented above).